# Attaching Fragments to Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created two activities and used intents to switch from first activity to second. Also I used  fragments in the second activity. When I tried to run the app,the app gets started and it stops unfortunately. When I remove fragments from my app, the app runs. What should I do to get rid of this error? This is my code...

```
First Activity code

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);

          }
        });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Second Activity code

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
}

public void selectFrag(View view) 
 {      
     Fragment fr;

     if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) 
     {
         fr = new FragmentOne();        


     }

     else if(view==findViewById(R.id.button3)){

         fr = new FragmentOne();         

     }
     else
     {
         fr=new FragmentOne();
     }

     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_first, fr);

     fragmentTransaction.commit();


 }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Fragment code

```
 public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,

              ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

               //Inflate the layout for this fragment           

              return inflater.inflate(

                      R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
              }
```

}

Manifest of Second Activity in which I tried to use fragments

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FirstActivity" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
    android:text="@string/IDE" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fragment_first"
    android:text="@string/Applications" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fragment_first"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fragment_first"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:text="@string/Operating_Systems" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_first"
    android:name="com.example.test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />
```

Comment: How can i get the stacktrace? I did not enclose any try-catch statements!!!

Comment: Did you mean to say "layout" and not manifest?

Comment: Replace all if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) with if(view.getId() == R.id.button2)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to replace a static `Fragment`. Static `Fragments` (ones defined in xml) cannot be manipulated via `FragmentTransactions`.

Also, you are telling Android to inflate a `Fragment` called `com.example.test` here:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_first"
    android:name="com.example.test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />
```

Comment: How should I use fragments then? Is there any other way of achieving it?

Comment: Please read the Android [`Fragment Guide`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

- First, create a container in your **FirstActivity**'s layout
- Secondly, using the fragment manager, set **FragmentOne** to it
- That is pretty much all you need to get this working!